# What is the best strategy for implementing scheduled payment in Django

Tags: django, cron, payment

I wanted to implement scheduled jobs/actions in my DJANGO backend. 
Actions are basically deducting monthly recurring payment from the customer. Sending payment link say before 10 days etc. etc. The dates will be based on when the user buys the subscription.

I have never implemented scheduled jobs before. I know there are some ways like cron tabs and celery. 
I wanted to know what will be the best strategy/tool for scheduled payments.

So basically what I think i will do is that i will run the scheduled job every day at a particular time and will check the available candidates and will run the payment module.
Is this strategy correct to run jobs everyday. Are there any better methods available. Is there a way that jobs run automatically when say the customers new billing cycle arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the strategy you are following is correct. You can use celery, redis and crontab to execute the payment system.

So, firstly you can specify the schedules using crontab. Also, .delay() function will help you in triggering the jobs whenever customer`s new billing cycle arrives.

So, the flow will be, tasks get triggered when a new billing cycle arrives using .delay()
Then the celery worker will register the task and the schedules. Then you may use celery beat to run the tasks periodically. Also you may use redis as a message queue.

Read about .delay() [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html)

Read about celery configuration setting [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html)

Read about setting a task scheduler using celery [here](https://medium.com/@channeng/setting-up-a-task-scheduler-application-with-celery-flask-part-1-8652265050dc)